# Magento2 after transfer the site to new server:try clearing your cookies. err_too_many_redirect

Tags: magento2.3, admin, cookie

When I try to visit the admin URL.  I get a browser error that indicates too many redirects

I have tried the following to resolve it:

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

However, this did not resolve the issue.

What needs to be done to get this fixed?

Comment: Do you have your SSL certificate installed? If yes, try reinstalling the cert then flush the cache etc. Also ensure your certificate is issued for the required subdomain, eg www.

Answer (score 1):

Check `core_config_data` table and search for paths `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`.

Check if your server supports https. If yes than put your Url as `https://www.example.com/`, otherwise put `http://www.example.com/`

What is happening here is that you have put wrong protocol in base_url. When magento tries to redirect to that protocol url's than your server redirects back to the correct protocol's url. This loop keeps on going until you get err_too_many_redirects.